# Can't insert record with foreign key in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I've got a *user* table, and a *picture* table.

The *picture* table has an *uploader id* column which is a foreign key.
It refers to the *user id* column in the *user* table.

For some reason, when I try to insert a new record into the *picture* table, it's not working. No error messages pop up. It just doesn't insert the new record.

```
INSERT INTO picture (pic_url, pic_uploader) VALUES($picurl, $uploader);
```

*$picurl* is an image src path from a file upload. The uploaded files are in the right directory, and the exact same code works perfectly for an earlier record without a foreign key.

*$uploader* contains the foreign key value -- from a session variable that contains the *user id* of the user account -- but it's not inserting it into the table.

Here's the SQL for the tables, in case that helps...

Picture table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS picture (
  pic_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  pic_url varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  pic_uploader bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (pic_id),
  KEY pic_uploader (pic_uploader)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Picture constraints

```
ALTER TABLE picture
  ADD CONSTRAINT pictures_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (pic_uploader) REFERENCES user (user_id);
```

User table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
  user_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_name varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  user_img varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'img/defaultpic.png',
  user_email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  user_pword char(60) NOT NULL,
  user_stat enum('0','1','A') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
  UNIQUE KEY user_email (user_email)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Comment: Include your PHP code used to connect and write into database.

Comment: Problem can be with `VALUES($picurl, $uploader);`. Use single quotes around variables, as they are of string type. Example: `VALUES( '$picurl', '$uploader' );`

Comment: And, I suggest to use prepared parameter values and bind them with the query.

Comment: The code used to connect to the database is in a php include file, and its working fine for all the other queries. And I have single quotes around the variables in my code, so that's not it either.

Comment: For the `insert` query shown in your posting, can you show PHP code used. Say, for example, `$query = "INSERT ...`

Comment: mysqli_query($dbconn, "INSERT INTO `picture` (`pic_url`, `pic_uploader`) VALUES('$picurl', '$uploader')");

Comment: And what were the values in both of the variables `$picurl` and `$uploader`?

Comment: See, the issue seems mostly PHP related. You should have included PHP code used to your question posted. You better do it now.

Comment: Thanks, but it's started working now, for some reason. 
Now all I have to do is figure out why!

Answer (score 0):

There can be a reason that $uploader value does not exists in your user table as user_id.

First try to insert in simple way directly in db by any tool like sqlyog putty, mysqladmin etc.

```
INSERT INTO picture (pic_url, pic_uploader) VALUES('pic1', 'user1');
```

Make sure user1 should exist in user table. If it works fine then problem in your application other wise mysql will return an error by this we will be able to check the exact problem either it is due to foreign key or else. So do it and share results.

Answer (score 0):

IN your picture table you are using columns NOT NULL.

But you try to insert only two values in the insert command that's why data is not inserted.

Either insert data for all columns or make columns as NULLABLE.

Thanks